# Is there a way to select multiple array?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to select 2 rows:

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1,2];
```

Comment: Please share sample input, sample output

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example you can just use a more complex css selector with `querySelectorAll` to query what you need.

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myInput td:nth-child(1), #myInput td:nth-child(2)'))
```

`querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList which you will need to convert to an Array, thus `[].slice.call`

However if your question is to get the first to items of an existing Array use the `slice` method.

```
tds.slice(0,2)
```

---

JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/cLunop1v/7/